# Styles are not getting imported in component

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I'm trying to import styles from a CSS file and I'm not able to import anything. Here is how I'm importing it

```
import React    from 'react'

import * as styles from './styles.css'

/* eslint-disable */
console.log('******************************************')
console.log(styles) // /styles.[hashValue].css
console.log('******************************************')

export default function SideNav() {
  return (
    <div className={'navBar'}>{'Side Nav'}</div>
  )
}
```

I'm using Webpack to bundle. Here is CSS handler code:

/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin'

```
const devStyleConfig = [
  {
    loader  : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    options : {
      hmr : true
    }
  },
  {
    loader  : 'css-loader',
    options   : {
      importLoaders    : 1,
      modules          : true,
      sourceMap        : false,
      camelCase        : true,
      localIdentName   : '[path][name]--[local]--[hash:base64]'
    }
  },
  {
    loader  : 'postcss-loader'
  }
]

export default devStyleConfig
```

Here is the [link to my full webpack config](https://gist.github.com/iiison/372a7a96d75bbe3b475faacb29d93056). Not sure what am I missing here.